# Fully drain water tank when it gets full with no external power

Tags: pressure, water, fluid-statics, flow, volume

This is something I want for my home, not a scholar exercise.

I have a tank that fills slowly because it is there to capture drops from a leak. This tank is on top of my house.
I want this tank to **fully empty** when the water level gets to a certain point (almost full).
Some sort of siphon which "activates automatically". I want a mechanism that will trigger based only on the weight of the water in the tank (or more precisely, only on the atmospheric pressure), with no other source of power. No electricity, no pumps. Once it gets activated it should empty the whole tank. I think I've seen something similar in laundry machines in the soap compartiment. Obviously the drain pipe needs to be close to the bottom of the tank, in order to empty it. I need some trick to fill the drain pipe with a column of water that will be enough to "start vacuuming".

Comment: Consider it as the opposite problem to a standard American toilet tank flushing mechanism...

Comment: I selected David's answer as best because that's what I was thinking all along. I arrived to the same solution before reading your answers (sorry it is in Spanish: https://twitter.com/racter/status/1343227834828005376). Also special thanks to @mark-h for the full and colorful description of the other idea I was considering. In my case I need to drain from the top :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has already been solved, a LONG time ago by Pythagoras of Samos, who invented a wine cup that would be self draining if filled too full.  The same idea can no doubt be used to drain your tank.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_cup

Answer (score 2):

This solution is inspired by American-style flush toilets. The drain plug mechanism consists of 2 parts: a plug that is hinged at one end and buoyant on the other, and a float with a chain to the buoyant end of the plug. The picture below shows the tank when it has just started to fill with water after being emptied:

[image: A self-draining tank that is partially full with the plug closed]

Here, the plug is in red. The hinge is on the left end and the buoyant plug on the right end. It is held closed by the weight of the water above it. This hinged plug is chained to a float (float is the white circle, the chain is the black line) that stays on the surface of the water in the tank. The chain will remain slack until enough water has entered the tank to raise the float and tension the chain. The length of the chain determines when the plug gets pulled out. See the next picture, below:

[image: A self-draining tank that has been filled enough for the float to pull the plug and start draining.]

The plug must be pulled far enough away from the drain that the flowing water does not  prematurely pull the plug closed. Once this happens, the water begins to drain out and, because the end of the plug is buoyant, the plug stays open until all the water is drained out. See the next picture, below:

[image: A self-draining tank that is in the process of draining and has drained enough that both the float and the buoyant end of the plug are floating on the surface.]

Because the end of the plug is buoyant, it will stay on the surface as the water drains (notice that both the plug stays open even when the float has descended with the water level and the chain is slack). Only when the tank is nearly empty will the plug once again reach the drain and close it.

You will need to experiment with the size of the float, the length of the chain, and the size of the plug/drain to get everything working correctly. The float needs to be big enough to force open the plug before it is completely submerged. The chain needs to be the right length to activate at the right water level. The drain and plug needs to be small enough that the float can pull it loose while being large enough to drain the tank in a reasonable amount of time.

In fact, the shape of the float should probably be a long cylinder chained at one end instead of a sphere as pictured. This way, if the float is almost submerged when the plug is pulled loose, then it will float much farther up afterwards, pulling the plug farther from the drain hole.

Comment: I have my doubts that this would work.  The OP should set up a small version to test the idea out before implementing on the full scale tank.

Comment: @DavidWhite This is true.

Comment: Floating toilet flapper valves are very reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism you are asking about (used in laundry machines) is called an Pythagorean siphon.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg8KQfaT9xY
[image]

By the way, the siphon tube doesn't need to be in the middle. It can along one of the sides (makes construction easier).

The hiccup with that in your case is that the leak is probably too slow to fully fill up the opening to get the siphon action started. If that happens the overflow will just slow drip down the tube.

Use the smallest diameter tube you can get away with to help alleviate this (I would have liked 1/64" inner diameter but can't seem to find anything smaller than 1/32") but your leak is probably slow enough that you will also need to add a small cup on a spring loaded hinge that tips over when too much water is in it. In that way, water is dumped into the siphon bucket in sufficient quantities to initiate the siphon action.

Comment: In fact, why not forget the siphon and use a *large* cup to collect the water, tip over and dump the water into a funnel and then into a tube, and then return to the up-right position  A bamboo tipping fountain, in fact https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shishi-odoshi

Comment: @DJohnMBut I guess you don't even need a spring if you properly choose the fulcrum. But a tipper can only empty the water from where the leak is to somewhere immediately adjacent. A siphon is easier to pipe away and far cooler.

Answer (score 0):

if you can have a hole at one side, the tank will empty, when the red line is reached, down to the level the inner pipe ends.[image]

Comment: The water level will never reach the red line. Water will start to leak out the side when its height reaches the apex of the lower wall of the pipe (2 squares below the red line). The water level will then stay there indefinitely.

Comment: @MarkH It should work with small diameter tubing due to surface tension of the water.